# Get back generated QR code from zxing encode

Tags: java, android, zxing

I've been using zxing (including the core.jar in my project) to generate QR codes using the examples with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false);
startActivity(intent);
```

However instead of calling a new activity I would like to get back the encoded image, so I can use the image in a custom activity of my own.

Is there a way to do this with zxing?

Answer (score 2):

You want [zxing.encoder.Encoder.encode()](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel,%20com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.QRCode%29)

Comment: @phalt this link is correct my dear friends. i have work on QR code by zxing encode

Comment: I've been using this, as you suggested, and I can get back a QRCode object with data but not as a bitmap. The other solution below suggets getting back a bitmap which would be ideal but my core.jar does not include that part.
Akash - you have done this before? Care to share more than just a comment on how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat messy, but if you look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java), it shows you how your intent is translated into an actual QR code. You'll need to rip out the specific pieces you want, but the `encodeAsBitmap` function looks like it gives you an `android.graphics.Bitmap` that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not return the encoded QR code via Intent. (Though your user can press Menu, then Share, to send or save the image.) You need to encode the content on your end using the `Encoder` class.

Comment: Sean, any example for how to do that?I would like to embed a URL in the QR code